# How to write a python script to open applications in linux mint

Tags: python, linux, shell, ubuntu, linux-mint

Hi I would like to write a python script so that if i run that script it should open couple of applications and run some commands in console.Can any one guide me through it. Like example scripts and location to place it etc .
P.S: I use Ubuntu as 17 as my OS.

Thankyou

Comment: its different it isn't the same really he is calling for opening and running an application

Answer (score 1):

You can use os.open command to run any script within python script it will run as it would in a command line, for example:

```
import os


os.open("echo 7")

#this will print 7 on the terminal when you run the script
```

If in case you want to capture output of a script you run and use it in the script then I suggest you use `os.popen`, for example:

```
import os 

var=os.popen("cat /path/to/file")

print(var)

#this will print the file content
```

So in short anything that goes in os.open("here") will run as it would in a command line or terminal of your os.

If you want to run applications you will have to sub subprocess:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call("spyder")
```

Alternatively you can use popen as well to open files:

```
import os

os.popen("spyder or subl")
```

`os.open` will not work. In regards to your specific request use the following code:

```
import os 
os.popen("cd /home/mypc/path ; subl")
```

Comment: so if i import os and write os.open("subl .") it should open sublime text editor rit

Comment: no it will not work on that, modified to open files, os.open will execute commands

Comment: I am able to open the application but i need to open it after navigating to certainpath how can i do it

Comment: i didn't really got your point please explain a bit more. you mean open application through some path like /home/etc ???

Comment: yeah first i want to navigate to some folder and then i want to open the editor at that path

Comment: okay made the edit for that

Comment: Its not working it is opening the application in the last path i used :(

Comment: Can you share the part of the code here???

Comment: I do not use subl but I believe you can open in in a directory by simply subl '/home/mypc/pathtodir'

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **os** library to execute system commands

```
import os
os.system("your command")
```

you can add your wanted application to the system path to be able to execute it using system commands